# Why when I import an SQL database via phpMyAdmin the import does not complete

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, phpmyadmin

***Hello!***As mentioned in the title when i import an SQL database via phpMyAdmin , the import does not complete

Actually i have more than 20 or 30 tables (anyway) but in the end of the operation i have just 16 tables or less !

It would not be a problem of encoding that of utf-8 ?

I must say that I use French in my work .. and this may be the cause of all this ?

if yes how do I remedy this problem

a red error appear in the top of the page :

**Error
Static analysis:
2 errors were found during analysis.
Unexpected character. (near "\" at position 3801)
Ending quote " was expected. (near "" at position 4585)**

align: left; background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);\" width=\"520\">\r\n

#### Topic of your message

\r\n\r\n  Subtitle for your message\r\n    \r\n \r\n   \r\n \r\n  \r\n \r\n    \r\n \r\n    \r\n \r\n \r\n  \r\n \r\n    \r\n

## Dear {subtag:name},

\r\n  Your message here...
\r\n \r\n    \r\n    \r\n \r\n \r\n  \r\n \r\n    \r\n \r\n    \r\n \r\n \r\n   \r\n \r\n \r\n\r\n\r\nNot interested any more? {unsubscribe}Unsubscribe{/unsubscribe}\r\n', '', NULL, 1, 0, 1, 'newsletter-4', 'a:10:{s:6:\"tag_h1\';s:76:\"color:(2, 'Newspaper', '', '\r\n{readonline}This e-mail contains graphics, if you don\'t see them **» view it online.**{/readonline}\r\n\r\n\r\n   \r\n  \r\n  \r\n   &nbsp

MySQL said: Documentation

1064 - syntaxe error near 'Newspaper', '', '

Sorry I see that the error code is not displayed completely .. that is why I post it as an image

[image]

How can i resolve this 
Thank you

Comment: Please help to resolve my problem :(

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using for the export and which version for the import?

Comment: Switch to the "mysql commandline tool".

Comment: thank you Isaac Bennetch and Rick James for answering ....

@Isaac  The version of the phpMyAdmin for export is : 4.6.5.1
and the import is 4.5.5.1 ....
i also must say that the export phpMyAdmin is a hosted online but for the import it's located in my local pc ....

Emm I think you gave me a good landmark :) .....
In reality I do not want to update my local server I am afraid of dysfunction of my websites in local .. this has already happened to me

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two possible problems here, but it's easy to make an educated guess.

I think your hosted version of phpMyAdmin is causing the problem when you perform the export. See the [phpMyAdmin 4.6.5.2 release notes](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.6.5.2/) which specifically mention a problem with exporting sequences including a backslash (which existed in 4.6.5.1). This sounds exactly like the problem you're having.

I definitely suggest upgrading the phpMyAdmin installation on your hosted/export server (or asking your host to, or [installing your own](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install) outside of the host's provided version). I'm quite confident this is the problem.

If that doesn't work, then there's still a chance it's the version to which you're importing. 4.5.5.1 is rather old, and there have been many fixes to the software library phpMyAdmin uses for parsing SQL queries. If you're not keen on upgrading that installation just to test, you can try importing a sanitized version of your file to the [phpMyAdmin demo server](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net) which is running the latest version. That way, you can at least determine if an upgrade will fix the problem.

tl;dr: phpMyAdmin 4.6.5.2 was released specifically to address issues with backslashes, which seems to be your problem here. Have your host upgrade your phpMyAdmin to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for all
Problem solved
The solution was to update phpMyAdmin
This means that the export version must be the same as the import version

Comment: In general phpMyAdmin doesn't care about which versions are used for importing and exporting, but in the case of this bug, it's true that one workaround could be to import using the same version that created the export. Another solution could be using a text editor search and replace (or sed or awk) to manipulate the .sql file. The best solution is to just not use the affected versions, of course :)